# I am reading in a CSV file and getting a Column out of range error

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am currently using EPPlus library and I am trying to read a csv file from a directory.  I am finding the file and trying to save it as an Excel but I am getting an exception `Column out of range` when I am trying to save it.

```
    string csvPath = path;
        string expath = "C:\\Users\\er4505\\Desktop\\Test CSV File";

        string exWorksheet = "Test99999";
        bool firstRowIsHeader = false;

        var xformat = new ExcelTextFormat();
        xformat.Delimiter = ',';

        var excelInfo = new FileInfo(expath);
        var csvFileInfo = new FileInfo(csvPath);

        try {
            using (ExcelPackage csvToExcel = new ExcelPackage(excelInfo))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = csvToExcel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(exWorksheet);
                worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(csvFileInfo,xformat,OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium25, firstRowIsHeader);
                csvToExcel.Save();

            }
        }
```

Comment: I was creating a CSV string and passing it into this library.  sorry I did disclose that, please view my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys spent last night going through all the documentation on this library.  This library is capable of receiving a list with out formatting it with comma separation.  I simply passed in my query result list and the library did the rest.

```
List<Engagement> QueryResult = PMService.GetRequestedEngagments(test);

var filename = yourfilename;
var path = @"C:\Users\er4505\Downloads" + filename;
var excelFileInfo = new FileInfo(path);         

try
{
    using (ExcelPackage csvToExcel = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = csvToExcel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(filename);
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(QueryResult, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium25);
        csvToExcel.SaveAs(excelFileInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found out, that problem was in my .csv file.

EPPlus library reads file and splits it to string array. The separator pattern is "\r\n".
But my .csv file had just '\n' symbol at the end of each line.

That's why EPPlus thought, that there're no lines in my .csv, but it had too many columns (official column limit is 16384).

The solution:

```
        var text = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\example.csv");

        ExcelTextFormat format = new ExcelTextFormat();
        format.Delimiter = ';';
        format.Culture = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString());
        format.Culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd.mm.yyyy";
        format.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

        //Replacing current "\n" NewLine symbol to "\r\n"
        text = text.Replace("\n", "\r\n");

        using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromText(text, format);
        }
```

Comment: I had a csv with a mixture of \r\n and \n.  Replace did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code in a console application, renamed "Test CSV File" to "Test CSV File.XLSX" and used NuGet to download EPPlus 4.0.5. Then I made a CSV file with three rows and two columns:

```
    Column1,Column2
    1,2
    a,b
```

After running the code the file is saved and you can open the output file in Excel. Removing the "XLSX" extension or "2" in the input file does not produce the error you mentioned. You can find the EPPlus code [here](https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus), so it is possible to download it and debug your problem. The error message you mentioned is used in [ExcelRange.cs](https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelRange.cs), line 144. Can you give more information about the input file so people can reproduce your steps?

Comment: You renamed the file from `.csv` to `.xlsx`? Or you saved it in the `.xlsx` format?

Comment: I changed the last part of the string in the expath assignment. Could be a typo in the original question

Comment: yes, I was becoming frustrated.  It seems like I was trying to do all the work manually.  Where as this library is able to revive a list or array from a query search and produce the excel file on the fly.  Please view the answer below